# What does this reoccuring allert mean "NEW MMS message to download: size is 1KB, expires on ___, _:__PM."

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, sms, mms, nexus-6

I get this all the time from contacts who insist they never sent me anything. Any clue?

I have a suspicion that somehow it is an error relating to others using imessage trying to contact me? or not?